# Processing code converted to Java using Eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

As mentioned in my other post, I'm a beginner in Java. I'm trying to run codes from Processing create spheres based on sales data and converted them to Java using Eclipse IDE and encountered errors below after running code.

Also in lines where it show float m and float m2 (message when I hover the cursor shows "the value of the local variable m2 is not used". I would appreciate any help.

```
    import java.awt.Color;

    import processing.core.*;
    import processing.core.PVector;
    import processing.data.Table;
    import processing.data.TableRow;


    public class UsingProcessing extends PApplet {
    Table table;
    int ballcount = 11;
    //int ballcount = table.getRowCount(); //NullPoint Exception error happening     here
    PVector[] orgin = new PVector[ballcount];
    float[]radii = new float[ballcount];
    Balls[]balls;
    Color[]cols = new Color[ballcount]; 

    public void setup(){
    background(255, 127, 245);
    noStroke();
    ortho();

    table = loadTable("HW 1 Data.csv", "header");
    println(table.getRowCount() + " total rows in table");
    balls = new Balls[table.getRowCount()];

    for (int i = 0; i<table.getRowCount(); i++){
        TableRow row = table.getRow(i);
        int product = row.getInt("Product");
        int sales = row.getInt("Sales");
        int category = row.getInt("Category");

        //Add to Arrays
        orgin[i]= new PVector(width/2, height/2);
        balls[i] = new Balls(product,sales,category);
        radii[i] = (sales/30000);
        if (category == 1) {
           cols[i]= new Color(255, 30, 50);
        }  else if (category == 2){
           cols[i]= new Color(100,255,50);
        }  else {
           cols[i]= new Color(100,50,255);
      }

       //cols[i]= color(150,100,150,200);
      }
    }

     public void draw() {
         background(50);
         shininess(45);
         lightSpecular(255, 255, 255);
         directionalLight(254, 254, 254, 1, 1, -1);
         specular(225, 225, 225);
 ambientLight(90, 90, 90);
 ambient(90, 90, 90);

 // orb-orb collision
 for (int i=0; i<orgin.length; i++) {
   for (int j=1+1; j<orgin.length; j++) {
     float r2 =  radii[i] + radii[j];
     float d = dist(orgin[i].x, orgin[i].y, orgin[j].x, orgin[j].y);
     if (d < r2) {
       if (d==0) { // avoid dist of 0
         orgin[i].add(new PVector(random(-.1, .1), random(-.1, .1)));
       }
       PVector axis = PVector.sub(orgin[i], orgin[j]);
       float m = axis.mag();
       float m2 =  radii[i] + radii[j] - m;
       axis.normalize();
       PVector temp = new PVector();
       temp.set(orgin[i]);
       orgin[i].x = orgin[j].x + axis.x*r2;
       orgin[i].y = orgin[j].y + axis.y*r2;
       orgin[j].x = temp.x - axis.x*r2;
       orgin[j].y = temp.y - axis.y*r2;
     }
   }
 }

 for (int i=0; i<orgin.length; i++) {
   fill(cols[i].getRGB());
   pushMatrix();
   translate(orgin[i].x, orgin[i].y);
   sphere(radii[i]);
   popMatrix();

   // boundary collison
   if (orgin[i].x > width-radii[i]) {
     orgin[i].x = width-radii[i];
   } else if (orgin[i].x < radii[i]) {
     orgin[i].x = radii[i];
   } 

   if (orgin[i].y > height-radii[i]) {
     orgin[i].y = height-radii[i];
   } else if (orgin[i].y < radii[i]) {
     orgin[i].y = radii[i];
   }
 }
}

private float random(double d, double e) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

class Balls {
   int product; 
   int sales;
   int category;;
   int radius;

   boolean over = false;

   Balls(){
   }
   Balls(int product, int sales, int category){
     this.product = product;
     this.sales = sales;
     this.category = category;
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

PApplet.main("UsingProcessing");

}
public void settings(){
size(1200, 700, P3D);

}


}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLException
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.createPGL(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:668)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.<init>(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:532)
    at processing.opengl.PGraphics3D.<init>(PGraphics3D.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2227)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2306)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10399)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10338)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10094)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10076)
    at UsingProcessing.main(UsingProcessing.java:126)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.opengl.GLException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: com/jogamp/opengl/GLException
    at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2260)
    at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2306)
    at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10399)
    at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10338)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10094)
    at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10076)
    at UsingProcessing.main(UsingProcessing.java:126)
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

The `m2 is not used` error is just a warning. It has nothing to do with your error.

Your error is caused by your code trying to use a class that's not on your classpath. You need to fix your classpath.

To modify your classpath, right-click your proeject, then go to properties, then go to Java build path. You need to add the library jars to your classpath.

Comment: thanks @KevinWorkman. Fixed by adding ALL libraries to the right classpath. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Also when importing processing jars remember to add all the content of core\library which contains the libraries to access native code to use openGL and other processing features

gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar
...
jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar
...
ecc...

m and m2 are unused variables, the IDE is telling you that they are out of scope of any possible interaction (you are not using them and he can tell)